# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 - when using Custom List Forms

Tags: custom, list, custom-form

Can anyone help ?

I run into a strange problem.
I have a custom List designed in Visual Studio 2010 with Custom Content Type.When I add Item to the list using default forms everything works ok.

When I add a custom New Item form and set it up as default (using SharePoint Designer) I receive this exception:

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904

I re-created a list (SQLExpress) - the same issue
I re-created the List on another Server (SQL Server 2008 R2) - the same issue

**ULS Logs**

Unknown SQL Exception 206 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

SqlCommand: 'SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @ItemId int,@@iRet int,@ExtraItemSize int,@DN nvarchar(256),@LN nvarchar(128),@@S uniqueidentifier,@@DocUIVersion int,@@Level tinyint;SET @@S=@wssp0;SET @@Level=@wssp1;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512;EXEC @ItemId = proc_GenerateNextId @wssp2;BEGIN TRAN;SET @DN=@wssp3;SET @LN=@wssp4; SELECT @ExtraItemSize = 0  EXEC @@iRet = proc_AddListItem @SiteId =@wssp5,@WebId=@wssp6,@ListID=@wssp7,@RowOrdinal=@wssp8,@ItemDocType=@wssp9,@SortTypeReversed=@wssp10,@RetainId=@wssp11,@RetainObjectIdentity=@wssp12,@ItemId = @ItemId OUTPUT,@ItemDirName=@DN OUTPUT,@ItemLeafName=@LN OUTPUT,@UserID=@wssp13,@TimeNow=@wssp14,@CopySecurityFromMasterID=@wssp15,@UseNvarchar1ItemName=@wssp16,@ServerTemplate=@wssp17,@IsNotUserDisplayed=@wssp18,@Basetype=@wssp19,@Level=@wssp20,@UIVersion=@wssp21,@tp_GUID=@wssp22,@CheckSchemaVersion=@wssp23,@OnRestore=@wssp24,@AddNamespace=@wssp25,@CheckDiskQuota=@wssp26, @tp_ID = @wssp27, @tp_ContentTypeId = @wssp28, @nvarchar1 = @wssp29, @tp_Modified = @wssp30, @tp_Created = @wssp31, @tp_ModerationStatus = @wssp32, @nvarchar3 = @wssp33, @nvarchar4 = @wssp34, @nvarchar5 = @wssp35, @float1 = @wssp36 , @bit1 = @wssp37, @bit2 = @wssp38, @bit3 = @wssp39, @bit4 = @wssp40, @bit5 = @wssp41, @bit6 = @wssp42, @bit7 = @wssp43, @bit8 = @wssp44, @ntext2 = @wssp45, @uniqueidentifier1 = @wssp46, @ntext3 = @wssp47, @ntext4 = @wssp48, @ntext5 = @wssp49, @Size=@wssp50, @ExtraItemSize = @ExtraItemSize ,@ItemName=@wssp51, @eventData=@wssp52, @acl=@wssp53, @DocClientId=@wssp54; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END  EXEC @@iRet = proc_EnsureTranLockNotRequired @wssp55, @wssp56, @wssp57;IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END; EXEC proc_UpdateDiskUsed @@S,1;COMMIT TRAN; DONE: SELECT @@iRet, @ItemId '     CommandType: Text CommandTimeout: 0     Parameter: '@wssp0' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'c194b88e-dc85-4ef0-b6eb-fe132eae1381'     Parameter: '@wssp1' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '1'     Parameter: '@wssp2' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '57f9ee38-0393-4edc-a70d-ca4dc0322780'     Parameter: '@wssp3' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'sites/collection/test/Lists/DevReq'     Parameter: '@wssp4' Type: NVarChar Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp5' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'c194b88e-dc85-4ef0-b6eb-fe132eae1381'     Parameter: '@wssp6' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '893f4f58-7c2d-4333-844f-904e2930ea5c'     Parameter: '@wssp7' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '57f9ee38-0393-4edc-a70d-ca4dc0322780'     Parameter: '@wssp8' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@wssp9' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@wssp10' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp11' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp12' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp13' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '1'     Parameter: '@wssp14' Type: DateTime Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '03/21/2011 14:27:42'     Parameter: '@wssp15' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp16' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'True'     Parameter: '@wssp17' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '100033'     Parameter: '@wssp18' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp19' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@wssp20' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '1'     Parameter: '@wssp21' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '512'     Parameter: '@wssp22' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '434939aa-9f54-4a74-8eb0-569c20bb691f'     Parameter: '@wssp23' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp24' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp25' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'True'     Parameter: '@wssp26' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'True'     Parameter: '@wssp27' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp28' Type: VarBinary Size: 8000 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp29' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'hhh'     Parameter: '@wssp30' Type: DateTime Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '03/21/2011 14:27:42'     Parameter: '@wssp31' Type: DateTime Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '03/21/2011 14:27:42'     Parameter: '@wssp32' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@wssp33' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'Group'     Parameter: '@wssp34' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'Intranet Development'     Parameter: '@wssp35' Type: NVarChar Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp36' Type: Float Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '7777'     Parameter: '@wssp37' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp38' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp39' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp40' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp41' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp42' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp43' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp44' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp45' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'hjjj'     Parameter: '@wssp46' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: ''     Parameter: '@wssp47' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'jjj'     Parameter: '@wssp48' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'jjj'     Parameter: '@wssp49' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'jjj'     Parameter: '@wssp50' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '110'     Parameter: '@wssp51' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'hhh'     Parameter: '@wssp52' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp53' Type: VarBinary Size: 8000 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp54' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp55' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'c194b88e-dc85-4ef0-b6eb-fe132eae1381'     Parameter: '@wssp56' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '57f9ee38-0393-4edc-a70d-ca4dc0322780'     Parameter: '@wssp57' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'True'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)

Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80131904

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)

Comment: What does your custom content type contain in terms of fields and what do you add to the new item form in SPD?

Answer (score 1):

The first line in your log entry suggests that you are pasing an int into a unique ID field.

You should check that the fields in your custom New Item form are consistent with your field types.